# How to implement a form with optional input fields in C?

Tags: c, console-application

I'm working on a console program that allows to search in an array of a structure named Person

For simplicity I'm now assuming that all of the attributes are integers.

```
typedef struct Person {
    int name;
    int city;
    int email;
} Person;
```

so the comparing function would look like this:

```
int comparing(int x, int y) {
    return x == y;
}
```

I'm trying to make a searching function that would allow the user to use `comparing(int x, int y)` and the user can search using one or more criteria. Meaning they can search by just name and email for example.

Comment: Dont understand why name is an `int`, but you can explore [do while()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop) for menu related operations

Comment: @irAM, just for simplicity, I'm just testing it now to make a clear algorithm and then it'll be easy to make it for strings.

Comment: let's say the user chose to search using name and city, how should the for loop look like to search?

Comment: @AymaneHrouch: I have now deleted my comments and formed them into an answer, in which I also provide a code example of a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have "checkboxes" that the user can check by moving the cursor on the screen with the arrow keys and then press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to activate them, then you cannot do this with the C standard library, but you probably can do it with a platform-specific API. For example, if you are on the Linux platform, you can use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). However, you might be better off creating a proper graphical application, i.e. not a console applicaton.

If you want to keep it a simple text console application using only the features of the C standard library, then you can have a text menu in which the user can specify that he wants to toggle a checkbox, and then it asks the user which checkbox number he wants to toggle. After every change of the checkboxes, the program reprints all checkboxes to show the user the new state of the checkboxes.

In the comments section, you specifically asked for code to show you how the loop of the search should look like. Therefore, I have written such a loop for you.

This loop requires that a variable of type `struct Person` with the name `lf` (which stands for "looking for") is created and filled with all search criteria. Only the fields that are actually being searched for have to be set. The remaining fields can stay uninitialized. Also, three variables of type `bool` must be created with the names `should_match_name`, `should_match_city` and `should_match_email`. These three variables must be set to specify whether to search for the corresponding field, and if set to `true`, the corresponding field must also be set in the `lf` variable. Note that you must `#include <stdbool.h>` to enable support for the `bool` variable type.

The loop could then look like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_valid_elements_in_array; i++ )
{
    if (
        ( !should_match_name  || lf.name  == array[i].name  ) &&
        ( !should_match_city  || lf.city  == array[i].city  ) &&
        ( !should_match_email || lf.email == array[i].email )
    )
    {
        printf(
            "Matching person found:\nName: %d\nCity: %d\nE-Mail: %d\n\n",
            array[i].name, array[i].city, array[i].email
        );
    }
}
```

Note that more sophisticated search algorithms (for example those used in database engines) do not search all elements in order to find a match, but they rather search using indexes. This makes the search significantly faster. These indexes would have to be created in advance, though. But as long as you have less than a million elements, it will probably not matter.